# How to make a token in Keycloak that never expires?

Tags: jwt, token, keycloak

I configured my realm.
[Token configs in real settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp1MS.png)

And I get jwt token:
[JWT token with exp date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tpnw.png)

It look like I could make a long lifespan token. But it exripes anyvay.
Is it possible to make a token that **never expires**?

Comment: Whats your requirement ? This is not a good practice at all.

Comment: I need to make a token for my client api.  I'm going to generate it once. And regenerate only if client wants to get new token.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do "never": instead, use a very long expiration time.
Go to your "Client" settings, "Advanced" tab, and set '365 days'.

[image]

There also is a "Never expires" option, but for some reason, it yields tokens that expire in 10 hours :D

In addition, you can use an "offline token": request a scope "offline_access" when getting a token, and you'll get a special "refresh_token" that has a very long expiration date. This is how OAuth2 does "token that never expire".

Comment: I tried setting the access token lifespan to 365 days for a service account/client_credentials style client, but I'm still getting back access tokens that expire in 10 hours.  I'm using Keycloak version 21.0.2.  Any ideas as to what could be overriding the client-specific configuration?

Comment: I found that the realm SSO session max was set to 10 hours, and somehow the client setting was unable to override the realm setting.  When the realm SSO session max was made to be 365 days, I was able to issue an access token that expires in 365 days.